# a proper adjective to describe a method that requiress a lot of efforts

Tags: word-request

I've come up with two words, but not sure if they are the most common collocations in this case.

> **laborious** method

> **arduous** method

Both of them sound rather formal to me. So, I would like to ask, how to make them sound more colloquial without changing the meaning here?

Comment: The two adjectives are not formal; they are specific to situations in which a great deal of effort, often physical effort, is required. Words such as **difficult / tough** are far more general and don't fit many contexts to which your two adjectives apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can say a ***demanding*** or ***challenging*** method, which is less formal than arduous and laborious.

A more neutral adjective would be ***difficult***.

If you want to be even more colloquial you could say ***a tough method***.